# AWS ALB Handshake resumption

Tags: ssl, https, tcp, amazon-alb

I have a problem where the AWS ALB TCP is initiated and every request which causes unnecessary latency of 0-150ms
[Example from postman to show what happens at every request. DNS lookup, TCP Handshake and SSL handshake are all initiated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XbfC.png)

And when I access the instance directly. The aforementioned does not occur.
[Another example from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPKLz.png)

Thanks and any help is appreciated.

On the load balancer, I'm using the AWS certificates and since they can't get exported I'm using LetsEncrypt on the EC2 instances

Edit:
How can I prevent the ALB from re-doing the handshakes and dns lookup

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: To note when accessing the load balancer using http:// (the ssl handshakes doesn't re-initiate at every request).
The http listener just redirects to https with the same URI

Comment: sorry @AlexD edited

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Desync mitigation mode to Monitor causes this to be solved.
Found this just by experimenting with a different ALB. Hope this saves someone from the headache.